# zlib writing raw encoded stream

Tags: c, zlib

I'm trying to write a generic function that will write both an uncompressed and compressed file (depending on user input). According to zlib, you just have to set the gzopen mode to "w0" (no compression), but I still get the ZLIB header!

In the ZLIB manual it mentions it is possible to write raw data (no header/trailer) but it doesn't say how. How can I write a plain (raw encoded) file with zlib?

thanks,

Comment: Why are you using zlib to write a plain file, why not just write the file with... write()?

Comment: @Vality Just trying to keep it simple! Instead of having both fopen/gzopen, write/gzwrite, fclose/gzclose, etc... it would be nicer to use just ZLIB and just adjust some options depending on user input for both plain and zip files...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file using the [transparent mode "T"](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip):

```
#include <zlib.h>

int main()
{
  gzFile file = gzopen("/tmp/a.dat", "wT");
  (void) gzwrite(file, "test", 4);
  (void) gzclose(file);
}
```